# php convert fetch object key to numeric

Tags: php, arrays

I have below code to fetch records from db:

```
$items = $post->get_list('news', $lang);

while($item = $items->fetch_object()){
    $res[] = $item;
}

foreach($res as $re){
    echo $re->pid.'<br>';
    echo $re->title.'<br>';
    echo $re->content.'<br>';
}
```

Base on some circumstance, I need to fetched data in `$re[2]` form instead of `$re->content`, what is the proper way to convert data as what I need?

Comment: You are using fetch_object that returns object. You have to use fetch_array instead

Comment: this should work `$re[2]->content`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `fetch_object` which return object format. If you want array format you can use `fetch_row`

```
while($item = $items->fetch_row()){
    $res[] = $item;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Answer (score 0):

you should use mysqli_fetch_array() in place of fetch_object() because fetch_object() returns you result in form of object. so to get result in form of array you should use mysqli_fetch_array() or mysqli_fetch_assoc().

Comment: okay i will remove it. but i thought this is answer for his question so.